# Javascript date objects always one day behind

Tags: javascript, html, date

I am trying to convert a date object from the backend db to a string to present on the view, however, when I convert it, the result is always one day behind.

The code:

```
date = this.props.date;

d = new Date(date)
    options = {
      month: "long", weekday: "long", year: "numeric",
      day: "numeric"
    };

    dateStr = d.toLocaleDateString("en-us",options)
```

EDIT examples provided:
Regarding backend structure, the date is inserted into the database via a simple html datepicker form.

Currently, this.props.date, if rendered on the view, will render something like this:

```
"2016-10-01"
```

When I use the code above, it would become:

```
"Friday, September 30, 2016"
```

Comment: How does your backend object look like?

Comment: please provide an example value for this.props.date, and the (incorrect) result you get.

Comment: Probably a timezone problem. Check your local timezone. Compare to ISO date (date.toISOString())

Comment: Use a proper [date-lib](http://momentjs.com/) which will handle many of your date issues in JavaScript.

Comment: @DrHund See edits above, also I ran your function and got 2016-10-01T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: I am getting the correct result with your code, can prepare a jsfiddle example

Comment: What do you see in the alert here? https://jsfiddle.net/fyr67ttf/

Comment: @BenM exactly!! I am getting the same result

Comment: @BenM I am getting "Friday, September 30, 2016" in the alert...

Comment: Is `"2016-10-01"` a local or UTC date? I'm guessing UTC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your backend date is in UTC specifically ISO8601 and you want the displayed date to be UTC in en-us language-region.

```js
var date = "2016-10-01";
var parts = date.split('-');
parts[1] -= 1;
var d = new Date(Date.UTC.apply(null, parts));
options = {
  month: "long",
  weekday: "long",
  year: "numeric",
  day: "numeric",
  timeZone: 'UTC'
};

document.getElementById('out').textContent = d.toLocaleDateString("en-us", options);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Assuming the date is UTC and the Date object handles ISO8601 correctly (some older versions do not) then you could rely on the built in parsing of Date.

```js
var date = "2016-10-01";
var d = new Date(date);
options = {
  month: "long",
  weekday: "long",
  year: "numeric",
  day: "numeric",
  timeZone: 'UTC'
};

document.getElementById('out').textContent = d.toLocaleDateString("en-us", options);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

So all I have done is explicitly set the output to be UTC, otherwise it is using your runtime's default time zone. Worth noting that `toLocaleDateString` is still in its infancy and can vary across browsers, just like ISO8601 parsing.

Comment: "en-us" is a language, not a locale. ;-) *toLocaleDateString* is entirely implementation dependant and support for the [*EMCA-402 Intl object*](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-402.htm) on which this answer depends is [*not ubiquitous*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl).

Comment: Actually it's  a language and region, CLDR often calls this a locale in the documentation but does explain that word locale, is not strictly correct, but is often used. But I can change that to language to be a little less contentious. :)

Comment: Bit of a personal grip, such settings are just preferences. I don't know why they need to be referred to as "culture" or "locale", both are misnomers in this context. :-(

Comment: But yes, it would probably be better to use the Intl Object instead of toLocalString, If available. Date in Javascript has been a bit of a malformed child from the get go, though I can understand why some of that is. :)

Comment: Yes, Date is a disaster really, time for an entirely new object based on the date from an existing language that is well thought out. The current attempts to fix it by tacking on ECMA-402 support and broken, half–baked support for ISO 8601 just doesn't cut it. There are serious bugs in existing implementations, particularly Safari, so the built–in Date really can't be relied upon for serious work.